# LockMode.READ in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, orm

I'm new to Hibernate and trying to understand more about the LockModes.

I found below text in book "Java Persistence with Hibernate":

```
LockMode.READ—Bypass all caches, and perform a version check to verify that the object in memory is the same version that currently exists in the database.
```

Does that mean, calling `session.lock(myObject, LockMode.READ)`, will refresh `myObject` state from Database? From "version check" I understand that Hibernate will check the version of `myObject` with Database, and if there is a difference it will synchronize instance of `myObject` with that of database.

I should also mention that after synchronizing the myObject instance with database, Hibernate will attach the myObject instance with persistence context (or session).

Isn't that correct?